# why the program is not terminating in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, getchar, putchar

Why the program listed below is not terminating. I am using gcc compiler in linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    printf("Enter characters: ");

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your input?

Comment: Do you ever input EOF?

Answer (score 3):

This program will terminate just fine when the conditions are met.  If you are on  Linux press CTRL-D which is the EOF input.  This will satisfy the condition and end the `while` loop.

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
```

This function will run forever, keeping your program from terminating until it gets a EOF input.  Check how to send EOF on your native system.  Once you input that the program will terminate.

Comment: *If you are on windows press Ctrl-D which is the EOF input.*... No, Ctrl-D works on Unix systems, such as linux or Mac/OS. on Windows you would type Ctrl-Z Enter

Comment: Great point, will correct!